# Session not being initiated from Guzzle Post

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, session, guzzle

I am integrating Laravel into a legacy php app. The login page used to directly post to `verifyUser.php` which also started a Symfony Session.

The new architecture now posts to a laravel api which makes a Guzzle post to `verifyUser.php`.

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#signIn').submit(function(){
    var a = $('#email').val();  
    $.post('/api/login', { //this used to post to verifyUser.php
      Username: $('#email').val(),
      Password: $('#password').val()
    }, function(data){
      if(data['credentials'] == true){
          console.log('credentials true');
          console.log(data['uri']);
          window.location.href=data['uri'];
      } else {
        $('#errMsg').html(data['errMsg']);
        $('.alert').show();
      }
    }, 'json');
    return false;
  });
```

controller functions:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request) //aka api/login endpoint
{
    //...
            $legacyRes = $this->authenticateLegacy($request);
    //...
}


private function authenticateLegacy(Request $request)
{
    $response = null;
    try {
        $response = $this->client->post('/admin/verifyUser.php', [
            'form_params' => ['Username' => $request->get('Username'),
                'Password' => $request->get('Password')]
        ]);
    }
    catch(Exception $exception){
        Log::error('Errrererererer', [$exception->getMessage()]);
    }
    $body = (string)$response->getBody();
    Log::info('BODY:', [$body]);
    return $body;

}
```

I have left out verifyUser.php because I have tested it and it returns the expected results.

When using the browser, the session information doesn't seem to get set. But according to my post responses, everything should be working.
Is this because I am routing the request through guzzle?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. We definitely need more information to be able to help you with your issue. Please include the relevant code parts in your question.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your legacy endpoint uses cookies to identify a user's session.

A successfull request to the legacy endpoint returns a `Set-Cookie` header.

Guzzle doesn't forward this `Set-Cookie` header from the API response to the browser - you'll have to program this behaviour into the "wrapping" application.

You will need to tell guzzle to explicitly pass the corresponding `Cookie` header to the legacy api (to maintain the user's login state) when sending any further requests.

In order to achieve this you'll need to save this cookie within your new application (i.e. in the user's session or in database) and then pass it within a `Cookie` header along with all further requests you make to the legacy API.

Comment: I see the cookie in the guzzle headers. I will try out your solution to make sure but I think this was my problem

Answer (score 2):

Posting under my answer to show updated code:

```
private function authenticateLegacy(Request $request)
{
    //...
    //parse cookie id from guzzle response
    $body = (string)$response->getBody();
    $cookie = $response->getHeader('Set-Cookie'); //PHPSESSID=SOMEID; path=/
    $cookieBite = explode(';', $cookie)[0]; ////PHPSESSID=SOMEID
    $cookieId = explode('=', $cookieBite)[1];

    $data = json_decode($body, true);
    $data['session'] = $cookieId;
    return $data;
}
```

In the action:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    //...
            $legacyRes = $this->authenticateLegacy($request);
    //...
    // this will have the session id in the body but will also 
    // set the cookie for the client so I don't have 
    // to set document.cookie w/ js
    return response($legacyRes, 200)
     ->withCookie('PHPSESSID', $legacyRes['session']);
}
```